# REST Framework: 404 on GET

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I wrote an `@api_view`, but `rest_framework`doesn't want to register it. So I get 404 when send a request on `api/main-filter/`. Why?

**rest.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def main_filter_options(request):
    r = {
        'regions': models.Region.objects.filter(city__category__isnull=False),
        'categories': models.Category.objects.filter(level=0),
        'years': tuple((str(n), str(n)) for n in range(2016, datetime.now().year))
    }
    return response.Response(r)
```

**api.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'main-filter', rest.main_filter_options, base_name='main-filter')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^api/', include('activities.api')),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routers only work with `ViewSets`, not `APIView` nor function based views.

You need to write an explicit url just like you do with regular Django views.

Comment: Well, how does your urls looks like now ? What about what makes you say it doesn't work ? Still got 404 ?